# Generating a unique ID in javascript (firstmiddlelastname)

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me on how to generate an user Id by using the first character of the first name and first character of middle name combined together with the last name with 4 numbers? All the information above is filled in into a form.

Comment: Can you share some of the code that you're working with? The format of the first name, middle name, and last name will help inform a quality answer. Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the first and last name, you can generate a random number and concatenate the values together.

For the random part we can use the `Math.random` function to generate a 4 digit number.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

To get the first character wen use the `charAt` function that is available on all strings.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt

```js
    var firstname = 'John'
    var lastname = 'Doe'
    var random = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000) // 4 digit random number

    // charAt(0) will give the first character in the string
    var userid = firstname.charAt(0) + lastname + random
    console.log(userid); // Example: "JDoe1234"
```

Comment: It would also be worth revising the answer to explain that the `charAt()` string method is the key to what the OP is asking for. Maybe provide a link to the documentation for it as well. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) ;)

Comment: Thanks! Updated with some more information regarding the used functions

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use a list or string of characters to randomly select from to generate ids

```js
const digits = "0123456789";
function createID(firstName,lastName,charCount = 4){
    var id = firstName[0] + lastName;
    while(charCount--){ id += digits[(Math.random() * digits.length) | 0] }
    return id;
}

console.log(createID("Blind","Man"));
```